# what is the correct way to process database?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

The code below only deletes the data when I add the extra statement in the controller. why is that?

I've only been using codeigniter for a few months now and I keep getting stuck with weird bugs like this.

this is the models file:

**My_model.php**

```
function delete_data($where=array())
{
  return $this->db->delete('table1', $where);
}
```

and the code in controller:

**tasks.php**

```
function do_delete_data()
{
  $this->load->model('My_model');
  $result = array('status' => '', 'message' => '');
  try
  {
    $this->db->trans_begin();
    $id = $this->input->post('post_id', TRUE);
    if ( ! $this->My_model->delete_data(array('id' => $id)))
    {
      throw new Exception('Database process failed.');
    }
    $result['message'] = $this->db->last_query(); // extra statement
    $this->db->trans_commit();
    $result['status'] = 1;
  }
  catch(Exception $e)
  {
    $this->db->trans_rollback();
    $result['message'] = $e->getMessage();
  }

  if ($this->input->is_ajax_request())
  {
    echo json_encode($result);
  }
}
```

it works fine until recently I tried to call this function via ajax like this:

**display.php**

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/tasks/do_delete_data',
  type: 'post',
  data: {
    'post_id' : $('#post_id').val(), // e.g. 12
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response) {
    alert('File deleted successfully.');
    console.log(response);
  },
  error: function(e) {
    alert('an error occurred.');
  }
});
```

Comment: u need to use `$id` with `$_POST`

Comment: @devpro I'm sorry, I was writing this question from memory and after I checked the code is wrong.. I edited the code. please take a look

Comment: yes, u r using wrong index name here `$id = $this->input->post('post_id', TRUE);` this should be `$id = $this->input->post('id', TRUE);`

Comment: check `print_r($_POST)` in controller and share the result also check browser console

Comment: when I replaced the extra statement with `print_r($this->input->post())` it gives `array([post_id] => 12)` which is correct. anyway, after I tested the code a few more times, I found out that the problem is in another part of the code. thanks anyway :)

Comment: u edited your code, and its looks fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `id` in ajax param but using `post_id` as in your controller, which is undefined index.

You need to correct your index name as:

```
$id = $this->input->post('id', TRUE); // use id
```

*It's better to check what are you getting in controller by using `print_r($_POST)` this will you to understand, what kind of array are you getting from ajax data.*